# slow review of dependent branches

Tags: git, branch

My Trainer is very busy, so he doesn't have always time to review my code.
I need to code and get something done.
Very often I code a feature in a branch and write down the architecture/information management for this and the next feature (next branch).
This makes the next branch dependent on the prior.
I just merge the prior branch into the next and continue coding.
When my Trainer now reviews (somtimes 8 branches) my code (with gitlab diff tool), he sees all the changes of prior branches (huge amount of code) and if he merges the branch he cant review the prior branch solely, since its already merged into the master.
Do you know any nice solutions of slow code review when branches depend on each other?

Answer (score 0):

I think for this strategy I would use `git rebase master` after having merged the older branch into master.  What happens there is that the history of your current branch is rewritten with the history of master.  If the older branch is already in master then the only new commits git will show is what you've changed that isn't in master since you've replaced the history of your feature branch with everything that is in the master branch.